# dbWriteTable equivalent in Python pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas

I'm looking for a way to insert a pandas dataframe into a table in SQL Server using Python.

I used to do this with an R one-liner:

```
dbWriteTable(con, "NAME_OF_DF", DF, overwrite = F, append = T, row.names = F)
```

So far I've only seen solutions where I have to insert the data into SQL Server with Python using a lot of code. I was wondering if there is a dbWriteTable equivalent in Python where you can also insert your dataframe in just one line.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) from `pandas`. Assuming `DF` is a DataFrame:

```
DF.to_sql("NAME_OF_DF", con, if_exists = 'append')
```